# I'm getting an error using playwright nth-match

Tags: python, playwright

I just discovered playwright and I'm trying to see if it would be better to use than selenium.  One issue I have is that none of the items in the application I write testing scripts for have names and this will not change.  I'm trying to use nth-math with text to find the second instance of "login" to click the "button" on the front page, but I keep getting an error.

Line that throws an error:

```
page.locator(':nth-match(:text("Login"), 2').click()
```

I also tried

```
page.click(':nth-match(:text("Login"), 2')
```

Both of these throw the same error
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: Unexpected token "" while parsing selector ":nth-match(:text("Login"), 2"

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis `:nth-match(:text("Login"), 2)`

Comment: @hardkoded - I updated and it doesn't show that error, but it is still not working.  It clicks the expected text and seems to keep running on the next page.  Since there isn't a login on the next page, it throws a time out

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ) after 2:

```
page.locator(':nth-match(:text("Login"), 2').click()
```

Use:

```
await page.click(':nth-match(:text("Login"), 2)');
```

Here is another way to do it that I find cleaner and more readable:
https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#n-th-element-locator

So in You case

```
page.click('button:has-text("Login") >> nth = 2')
```

Comment: Thanks - I fixed the paren as suggested by hardkoded above.  Thanks for the other suggestion, but this isn't a button.  I'll be able to use something like that elsewhere, though.

Answer (score 0):

.NET syntax - this worked for me

```
await page.Locator(":nth-match(:text('your text'), 2)").ClickAsync();
```